# Change factor levels conditional on the level frequency using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have got the following data set:

```
x = c(rep(0,600),rep(1,200), rep(2,100), rep(3,50), rep(4,20), rep(5,10), rep(6,10), rep(7,5), rep(8,5))
y = rbinom(1000,10,.5)
DATA = cbind(x, y)
```

Using

```
t_x = table(x)
```

I obtain:

```
x
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
600 200 100  50  20  10  10   5   5
```

As some of the levels are very rare I want to aggregate them such that each level is represented by at least 10% of the sample. The desired outcome after calling `table` on `x` should be:

```
x
  0   1   2  "higher" 
600 200 100      100
```

I have tried to use the following code:

```
DATA %>% mutate(x = if_else(t_x <= length(x) * .1, factor("higher", levels = c("higher", levels(x))),
            factor(x)
            ))
```

but `if_else` does not accept the `t_x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `cut` along the following lines:

```
brks <- as.numeric(names(t_x[prop.table(t_x) >= 0.10]))
DATA %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(x.new = cut(x, breaks = c(-1, brks, max(x)))) %>%
    pull(x.new) %>%
    table()
#(-1,0]  (0,1]  (1,2]  (2,8]
#   600    200    100    100
```

The resulting `table` gives the number of entries per interval, e.g. `600` entries in group `(-1, 0]` which corresponds to entries with value `0`, `200` entries in group `(0, 1]` corresponding to entries with value `1`, and so on.

Note that intervals are right-inclusive, i.e. for `(x, y]` the value `y` is included while `x` is not, see `?cut` for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for a response. Could you please tell me how to extract the `x.new` from your code? I actually need that new variable to conduct further inference.

Comment: @CherryGarcia just omit the last `table()` line from my example to get the `x.new` vector. Or just use `cut` directly on `x`. No need for a `dplyr` chain.